# Program which will display only alphabetical letters in the label, and give an error text for anything else

Tags: java, swing

I currently have my program display whatever key is pressed, ranging from letters to numbers and symbols. The problem is, I only want it to display the letters, and say "not valid" for everything else.

Here is what I have now:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    String keyCode = KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());

    statusMsg.setText("You selected " + keyCode);

}
```

Edit: Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: What is the text being entered into? A JTextField?

Comment: It is a JLabel.

Comment: If this were my application, I'd consider using a JTextField, perhaps dressing it up so that it looks like a JLabel, and then attaching a DocumentFilter to the JTextField's Document. I'd be trying to simplify by using components that *expect* text input, components that have filters for just this sort of thing, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `e.getKeyChar()` instead which will give you the char representing A if the user types in `shift + a` for example. That said, you have a couple options:

1. You could write a Matcher that only accepts alphabetic characters. This could look like `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]").matcher()`. Then you can check `matcher.matches(keyCode)` (e.g. `keyCode = matcher.matches(keyCode) ? keyCode : "Not Valid"` on the third line of your method)
2. You could just use the getKeyChar method above and check the int value is between 'a' and 'Z'. This would look like:

   char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
   String message = ((keyChar >= 'A' && keyChar <= 'Z') || (keyChar >= 'a' && keyChar <= 'z' ) ? "You selected " +    keyChar :  "Not Valid"
3. You can use the `Character.isLetter()` method

Answer (score 2):

Looking at JavaDoc for `KeyEvent` class ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)), it seems it has all the key codes defined as constants, e.g:

`public static final int VK_A`

> VK_A thru VK_Z are the same as ASCII 'A' thru 'Z' (0x41 - 0x5A)

So, you need to get the key code and make sure it's between `VK_A` and `VK_Z`. If not, you can show the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  

    String keyCode = KeyEvent.getKeyText(evt.getKeyCode());

    if (keyCode.length()==1 && Character.isLetter(keyCode.charAt(0))) {
        statusMsg.setText("You selected " + keyCode);
    } else {
        statusMsg.setText("Not valid");
    }

}
```

First it checks if the string's size is 1, because if it is bigger it means that the key is something like "Enter". Then, it uses the `isLetter` function of the Character class to check if the first char of the `keyCode` is a letter and not a number.

Answer (score 1):

[ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) codes...

```
int code = Integer.paseInt(keyCode);
if ((code >= 'A' && code <= 'Z') || (code >= 'a' && code <= 'z')){
  //code represents a letter key pressed
} else {
  //code does not represent a letter key pressed
}
```

Characters are understood as integers in the above code (e.g. `A` is 65).

Comment: Use `'A'` instead of 65, `'Z'` instead of 90, etc. Those numbers are less understandable. --- Also, method is named `parseInt`.

Comment: @Andreas, thank you. Corrected. Yes, because `keyCode` is a string in OP's code.